# Platform neutral unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing

I'm curious if there is a platform neutral way of defining unit tests.  Consider the task of defining some unit tests for a new set implementation with code bases in both Java and C#.  For example, we might want to test that {3, 4, 5} intersect {4} is {4}.  Instead of writing this unit test twice (once in our Java project and once in our C# project) it would be nice to define the test once (maybe in XML?) and then have each runtime read and execute that test automatically.  Some work would need to be done in each language to define how a set should be instantiated and populated, but it seems that we would only have to configure that detail once which seems reasonable when the payoff would be not duplicating n unit tests.

Does anyone know of a language or framework with this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed something along the lines you describe that enables you to define your tests at a high level and then generates the test harness source code in either C or C++.

http://www.apollo-systems.co.uk/dev/products/

Whether I extend it to generate C# and JAVA depends on demand. It is aimed primarily at the embedded systems market where C and C++ are the preferred languages.

The test specification is stored in XML and I have defined a minimum set of operations to allow you to do something useful. The motivation in developing this is to allow you to focus on what you want to test rather than writing test code.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with potential framework for such platform neutral unit testing:

- mapping between pieces of C# and Java code (as in, such tool would need to know which Java/C# method or class to test given certain say XML configuration file)
- differences between external libraries (even if you can make your own code in such way that translation could be easily achievable, external libraries providers might not - and most likely won't even care)
- languages differencies itselves

Sure, perhaps one can overcome those issues with fairly advanced and thought-through configuration file. But then another question is raised - is it still *unit testing* what we are doing? Unit test is **strictly bound to code it is testing** (being written in same language springs to mind as one of the firsts), there's really no smart way to go agains this rule. Writing "unit test" in XML..? That doesn't sound right.

There's this easy thing to remember - unit testing should be plain and simple process. Approach you're asking for would most likely make it overcomplicated. Writing tests in same language is straightforward - after all, you are supposed to be able to write implementation as well. Introducing extra framework introduces the need to learn it, maintain it and deal with possible new problems it might cause.

Overall, problem with tools targeting different platforms is always the same - there will be cases, when such tool is too general or platform limitations are too specific. And that's when you'll have to fallback to platform language/tool itself. So, even though it might sound appealing for **very simple** cases (like your intersect one), overall I don't think it's worth the effort. You'll end up doing stuff in mixed way anyways.